# How to get Task to appear in Case Feed

Tags: apex, lightning, case, tasks, casefeed

When I do to `Log a Call` on a `Case` it creates a `Task` record in the `Case` activity timeline and a entry in the `Case` feed.

But when I create a `Task` record against a `Case` using Apex, but it's not appearing in the `Case` feed.

How can I create a `Task` that's related to a `Case` which also appears in the `Case` feed?

Comment: Are you setting the `WhatId` to the current Case SFID?  Is this for Salesforce Classic and you're asking about the Chatter feed?

Comment: @BrianMiller it's for Lightning. I am setting the `whatId` to the `case.Id`

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: I can't reproduce the exact behavior you're describing; I *do* get feed posts in most cases, pun intended. Here's what I found.

There's some specialized behavior around [`FeedItem` posts linked to `Case` records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) (see under `Type`):

> `ActivityEvent`—indirectly generated event when a user or the API adds a Task associated with a feed-enabled parent record (excluding email tasks on cases). Also occurs when a user or the API adds or updates a Task or Event associated with a case record (excluding email and call logging).
>
> For a recurring Task with CaseFeed disabled, one event is generated for the series only. For a recurring Task with CaseFeed enabled, events are generated for the series and each occurrence.

I did a bit of testing and found the following -

```
// Feed: Yes
insert new Task(WhatId = '5001R00000gS4OxQAK', Subject = 'Test'); 
insert new Task(WhatId = '5001R00000gS4OxQAK', Subject = 'Test', TaskSubtype='Task'); 

// Feed: Yes, but the wrong icon (Task instead of Call)
insert new Task(WhatId = '5001R00000gS4OxQAK', Subject = 'Test', TaskSubtype='Call');

// Feed: No
insert new Task(WhatId = '5001R00000gS4OxQAK', Subject = 'Test Email', TaskSubtype='Email');
insert new Task(WhatId = '5001R00000gS4OxQAK', Subject = 'Test List Email', TaskSubtype='ListEmail');
```

The phasing of the documentation quoted above is confusing and seems to contradict itself. Call Logs *do* leave Chatter posts via both the UI and the API, as do regular Tasks, but Emails and List Emails do not when sent via Apex (I didn't test emails in the UI).

I've worked on the [Activity timeline](https://www.ktema.org/2018/07/11/lightning-activities-view/) before (link is to my blog) and found that there seems to be some behind-the-scenes magic going on in how the `TaskSubtype` is set and aligned to the visual presentation of the generated Chatter feed post - as seen here, when I try to synthesize a Call Log Task via Apex, and get a feed item that looks like a regular Task.

Comment: Thanks David. Out of interest, what type of object is being created to add an entry to the `case` feed? because if I query `SELECT Id, Title, Body, Type, Status, RelatedRecordId, ParentId, LinkUrl, HasLink, HasFeedEntity FROM FeedItem WHERE ParentId = 'CASE_ID'`, I only get 1 record of `type` = `CreateRecordEvent`, but no record for the Call Task I created.

Comment: @Robs I'm finding the same thing, although the feed items do show in the UI. That seems mysterious - I'm not sure how the mechanism actually works here.